# troubles with SharedArrayBuffer on localhost

Tags: javascript

I'm having a lot of trouble getting SharedArrayBuffer usable. I read a lot on the web that I have to activate cross-origin isolation, but how, what, where?

I use a localhost "KSWEB" on android. I keep reading this:

```
Cross-Origin Embedder Policy: require-corp 
Cross-Origin Opener Policy: same-origin
```

But where should I write that it works. it doesn't work in the header of the html file "index.html".

A complete working example with all the setups at every required point would be more helpful than the mountains of theoretical paraphrasing in the web that I have just need to create the cross-origin isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours i found a solution

https://github.com/gzuidhof/coi-serviceworker

This is a workaround but it works.
It works well and was easy and quick to understand

in my case my html looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>SharedArrayBufferTest</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <script src="coi-serviceworker.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">      
 </head>
 <body> 
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="./build/bundle.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```